# Wierd issue where ie9 debug console fixes issue

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a page where scrollbars are being made to appear via JQuery, and it does appear except in ie9(only IE version I can test with). It seemed the problem was due to compatibility mode, but even after adding the ie=edge meta tag, clearing cache and reloading the scrollbar didn't appear. However weirdly enough, as soon as I hit f12 to bring up the developer console and then refresh with f5, everything starts to run fine from that point onwards. The problem doesn't occur on the same PC again, but a different PC and the whole thing starts over. Do any of you have any idea why this might happen?

Here's the link:http://www.waterhouseresearch.com/shop.php

```
user:testing@gmail.com
pass:testing
```

and a screenshot of what it should look like:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/probimg.jpg/

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer, the `console` object doesn't exist until you open the Developer Tools (by pressing F12), so attempting to use, for example, the `console.log()` function to output to the console will throw an error.

Comment: Beat me to it! ;D
There's a console.log in jquery.dataTables.js on line 4539. Could be it.

Comment: I remove all the console.log() from my script but still remain same problem.